# Como verificar com jQuery se existe um checkbox checado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Gostaria de saber qual Checkbox está checado com Jquery.

Para pegar todos os check fiz os seguinte código

```
var checado=false;
$(obj).find("input[name='analisar']").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked")=="checked")
       checado=true;
});
if(!checado){
     alert("Deve ser selecionado uma opção entre Aprovado/Desaprovado!");
     return false;
}else....
```

Porém está retornando sempre que nenhum está selecionado. Como faço para ver se pelo menos um está selecionado.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/lionbtt/AGbCY/

Comment: Se puder fornecer também o HTML ou direto um jsfiddle com sua tentativa facilita dar uma resposta

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Utilize o método [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) ao invés do `attr`.

Elaborando a resposta: existe uma certa diferença entre atributos e propriedades dos elementos HTML. Deixo a seu critério estudar essa diferença ;) `checked` não é um atributo, mas sim uma propriedade. O método `prop`, conforme o link que menciono, foi inserido na versão 1.6 do jQuery para lidar com isso.

Comment: Valeu cara, era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 22):

O jQuery tem um atalho para isso, a pseudo-classe `:checked` (que faz parte do CSS3). Com isso dá pra reduzir bem o seu código:

```
var checado = $(obj).find("input[name='analisar']:checked").length > 0;
```

Comment: Se eu tiver mais de dois checado, como fica a variável `checado`? Ou seja, ela será um `object` ou ele vai retornar `boolean`?. Valeu.

Comment: Eu esqueci de acrescentar a verificação no final da linha. Veja se o length do objeto jQuery retornado é maior que 0, aí você garante um booleano.

Comment: Boa cara, vai ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 18):

A melhor forma é utilizar o `.is(':checked')` onde retorna um `boolean` da validação

Veja o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ek33a/

Answer (score 12):

```
if( $("#id_element").is(":checked") == true/false )
```

Comment: Podes juntar texto a explicar a tua resposta?

Comment: Achei fácil e me ajudou

Answer (score 4):

Para verificar se existe algum selecionado, você pode usar o `$(':radio').is(':checked');`

Segue um exemplo simples;
=D

```js
var ok = "#btnOK";
var clean = "#btnClean";
var radio = ":radio";
var msgbox ="#msg-box span";
var color;

$(ok).on("click" , function(){
  //Check se há alguma opção selecionada
  if($(radio).is(":checked")){

    $.each($("input[type='radio']"), function(id , val){
      if($(val).is(":checked")){
        color = $(val).val();
        return false;
      };
    });
    //var color = $(radio).is("checked").prop("id");
    console.log(color);
    $(msgbox)
    .html("Foi selecionado a opção <strong>" + color + "</strong>.")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("alert alert-success")
    .show();

    setTimeout(function(){
      $(msgbox).hide();
    } , 5000);                      
  } else {

    $(msgbox)
    .html("Não foi selecionado nenhuma opção")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("alert alert-danger")
    .show();

    setTimeout(function(){
      $(msgbox + " span").hide();
    } , 5000);

  }
});

$(clean).on('click' , function(){
  $(radio).prop("checked" , false); 
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
            <div id="msg-box">
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <h1>Selecio sua cor favorita</h1>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsColors" id="optYellow" value="amarelo" > Amarelo
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsColors" id="optBlue" value="azul" > Azul
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsColors" id="optWhite" value="branco" > Branco
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                 <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsColors" id="optBlack" value="preto" > Preto
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsColors" id="optRed" value="vermelho" > Vermelho
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsColors" id="optGreen" value="verde" > Verde
                </label>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnOK">
                    <span>OK</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnClean">
                    <span>Limpar</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

A partir do jQuery 1.6, o método `.prop()` fornece uma maneira de recuperar explicitamente valores de propriedade, enquanto `.attr()` recupera atributos.

**elem.checked** true(Boolean): Vai mudar o estado do checkbox
**$( elem ).prop( "checked" )** true(Boolean): Vai mudar o estado do checkbox
**elem.getAttribute( "checked" )** "checked"(String): Estado inicial do checkbox; Não muda
**$( elem ).attr( "checked" )** *(1.6)* "checked"(String): Estado inicial do checkbox; Não muda
**$( elem ).attr( "checked" )** *(1.6.1+)* "checked"(String): Vai mudar o estado do checkbox
**$( elem ).attr( "checked" )** *(pre-1.6)* "checked"(String): Mudar com estado do checkbox

```
var checado=false;
$(obj).find("input[name='analisar']").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
        checado=true;
});
if(!checado){
    alert("Deve ser selecionado uma opção entre Aprovado/Desaprovado!");
    return false;
}else....
```

Fonte: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Seria útil se você juntasse uma pequena explicação.

Answer (score 2):

```
function validaTermo() {

    var checado = $("#termo").is(':checked')
    if(checado == true){
        //checado
    }

    console.log(checado);
}
```

Comment: Em que é que a sua resposta difere das já existentes ?

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta é sobre jQuery, mas acredito que caiba uma alternativa com JavaScript puro:

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector("#checkbox");

if(checkbox.checked === true) {
    console.log("Está checada!");
}
```

Simplesmente fazemos a seleção do elemento e depois verificamos o valor de checked, se é true a checkbox está marcada.

Acredito que seja até mais simples essa alternativa que com jQuery, pois a propriedade checked é de fácil acesso.

Podemos inserir em uma condicional, testar seu valor e prosseguir com a lógica.