# Ativando evento a partir de checkbox

Tags: javascript

Eu tentei fazer o `checkbox` para mudar um `input` de `hidden` para `text`, mas não sei no que estou errando.

```js
function myFunction() {

    const selecionado = document.querySelector("#quant");
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("ch_quant");

    var input = document.getElementById("quant").type = 'hidden';


    if (checkBox.checked == true){
       document.getElementById("quant").type = 'text'
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("quant").type = 'hidden'
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="nome">Marque P/ Informar Estoque</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ch_quant" name="ch_quant" required>
  <input type="hidden" id="quant" name="quant">
</div>
```

Comment: Onde chamas essa função `myFunction`?

Comment: falou tudo não esta em nenhum lugar, teria como me mostrar como ficaria correto pois sou estudante então sou bem novato.

Comment: Sua pergunta tem resposta neste tópico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5563/como-verificar-com-jquery-se-existe-um-checkbox-checado usando jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo você deve chamar a função que criou quando houver alteração no `checkbox` com o `onchange="myFunction(this)"`.

Segundo, com o `this` você passa por parâmetro da função o próprio `input (<input type="checkbox" id="ch_quant" name="ch_quant" onchange="myFunction(this)" required>)`.

Depois disso é só verificar se está marcado ou não, assim como você já tinha feito.

```js
function myFunction(checkbox) {

  if (checkbox.checked)
    document.getElementById("quant").type = 'text'    
  else 
    document.getElementById("quant").type = 'hidden'
    
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="nome">Marque P/ Informar Estoque</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ch_quant" name="ch_quant" onchange="myFunction(this)" required>
  <input type="hidden" id="quant" name="quant">
</div>
```

Comment: Acho que vc quis dizer "com o `this` você passa por parâmetro da função o próprio **checkbox**" (não "o próprio input"). Outro detalhe é que vc pode simplesmente fazer `if (checkbox.checked)` - comparar um valor booleano com `== true` é redundante

Comment: O **checkbox** não é o **input**? Acho que sim, veja: `<input type="checkbox"...`

Comment: @Natan O hidden/text também é input, então acho que ficaria mais claro dizer qual dos inputs está sendo passado :) Foi isso que eu quis dizer. Desculpe se meu comentário ficou confuso

Comment: @hkotsubo exatamente, é o `input type="checkbox"` que é passado, poderia estar mais claro kk. Apesar de que está explicito que passa o 
 `próprio input`